# Create larger list from an existing list using a list comprehension or map()

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate a list to index coordinates (x, y and z), given a set of atom indices. My problem is quite simply how to elegantly go from this list:

```
atom_indices = [0, 4, 5, 8]
```

To this list:

```
coord_indices = [0, 1, 2, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26]
```

The easiest to read/understand way of doing this I've thought of so far is simply:

```
coord_indices = []
for atom in atom_indices:
    coord_indices += [3 * atom,
                      3 * atom + 1,
                      3 * atom + 2]
```

But this doesn't seem very Pythonic. Is there a better way I haven't thought of without getting a list of lists or a list of tuples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> atom_indices = [0, 4, 5, 8]
>>> coords = [3*a+k for a in atom_indices for k in range(3)]
>>> coords
[0, 1, 2, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26]
```

We can nest loops in list comprehensions in the same order we'd write the loops, i.e. this is basically

```
coords = []
for a in atom_indices: 
    for k in range(3): 
        coords.append(3*a+k)
```

Don't be afraid of `for` loops, though, if they're clearer in the situation.  For reasons I've never fully understood, some people feel like they're being more clever when they write code horizontally instead of vertically, even though it makes it harder to debug.

Comment: I believe that list comprehensions can be/are faster because they're pushed down to c-code. http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the answer, your comment is valid. However, I think in this case people would know quite clearly what was going on from the 3*a+k section.

Comment: @Imagine: the benefits are usually minor, though.  If what you're actually doing is expensive it'll dominate the loop cost, or you should be using something else like `numpy` anyhow.  And if it's not expensive to begin with, then it's not worth worrying about.  [BTW, I think you have the wrong link there.]